# Excel VBA - repeating macro through a column

Tags: vba, excel

I found this VBA code online. The code is meant to find specific text "Item", then delete the the cell that has the text "Item" and the cell below it. The code works but only one at a time. The column i'm working through has 11,000 cells of data. Going one at a time would take way too long. Does anyone know a way to take this code and make it work through the entire column with one run? Here is the code.

```
   Sub deleteCells()
'
' deleteCells Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
Cells.Find(What:="Item").Select
StartRange = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(1, 1).Select
EndRange = ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Range(StartRange & ":" & EndRange).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did, I tried a few variations but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted to. I still have a lot to learn in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting the cell you find so using .address to find the first find is not going to work. Just keep looking for *Item* until you cannot find it anymore.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteCells()
    Dim rng As Range, str As String

    On Error Resume Next
    str = "Item"
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set rng = .Cells.Find(str)
        Do While Not rng Is Nothing
            rng.Resize(2, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Set rng = .Cells.Find(str)
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

You should apply more parameters to the .Find operation. VBA's .Find is the same as on the worksheet and will inherit options (aka parameters) that the user has used.

You should also restrict .Cells to the column you want to work with. You decided that was not important enough to include in your question so you can figure that part out.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. It works. I dont know as much about code as I would like. I plan to keep learning. Thanks for answering my question.